# Get the type of a map returned object. Typescript ts(2345)

Tags: typescript

I have a code working with the `any` type, check the comment `//HERE TYPE ANY`:
I need that to be able to push data into that array, as you will be able to se below in the code in the `//NEED ANY TYPE TO PUSH INTO THE ARRAY` line.

```
const ProjectList = () => {
  const [projects, setProjects] = useState<IFirebaseProject[]>();
  useEffect(() => {
    let data:any[] = []; //HERE TYPE ANY
    firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("projects")
      .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
        let changes = snapshot.docChanges();
        changes.forEach(change => {console.log(change.doc.data())})
        const fbProjects = changes.map( (change) => ({
          id: change.doc.id,
          ...change.doc.data()
        }));
        fbProjects.forEach(fbProject => data.push(fbProject)) //NEED ANY TYPE TO PUSH INTO THE ARRAY
        setProjects([...data]);
      });
  }, []);
```

My problem is that I cannot enforce the type (although I know it) for the specific part of the code:

```
const fbProjects = changes.map( (change) => ({
    id: change.doc.id,
    ...change.doc.data() 
}));
```

I know the type obtained by `...change.doc.data()`, but how can I enforce my type, so that `fbProjects` meets a determined type which I define?

This is the type of `fbProjects`:

```
interface IFirebaseProject {
  id: string,
  authorFirstName: string,
  authorId: string,
  authorLastName: string
  content: string
  createdAt: Date
  title: string
}
```

So it has the id property, and I know that `...change.doc.data()` has the rest of the properties.

If I use my `IFirebaseProject` instead of `any` I obtain an error when I push the project in the array (`fbProjects.forEach( fbProject => data.push(fbProject))`) because obviously does not meet the type.

The error I obtain is:
`Argument of type '{ id: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IFirebaseProject'. Type '{ id: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'IFirebaseProject': authorFirstName, authorId, authorLastName, content, and 2 more.ts(2345)`

Edit:
Console output:

[image]

(One of this objects for each of the registers in the database logged with the `.forEach`)

Comment: What is the output of console.log(change.doc.data())?

Comment: I edited the question. See at the end

Comment: It is an object with all the fields of the `IFirebaseProject ` Interface except the Id. Then in the map function I compose the object with the `id` property to compose the whole type I need, and match the interface type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could tell TypeScript to treat the object returned from `map` as `IFirebaseProject`:

```
const fbProjects = changes.map((change) => ({
  id: change.doc.id,
  ...change.doc.data()
}) as IFirebaseProject);
```

Answer (score 0):

I split my types like this:

```
interface IFirebaseProject extends Destructured {
  id: string,
  
}

interface Destructured {
  authorFirstName: string,
  authorId: string,
  authorLastName: string
  content: string
  createdAt: Date
  title: string
}
```

Then I could set the type of the destructured part like this.

```
const fbProjects = changes.map( (change) => ({
    id: change.doc.id,
    ...change.doc.data() as Destructured
}));
```

That did the work. In case there is a more proficient way to solve this, I'll be glad to know.